# Xcode 5 to Xcode 4 Project Run

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios6

I have a project that I started in iOS SDK 6.  I downloaded Xcode 5 Beta with iOS 7 and ran it successfully.

However, to submit the project, I need to go back to SDK 6 and Xcode 4.  When I do, I get following message for every XIB file I have in the project:

[image]

How do I fix this so I can compile and run from SDK 6 and Xcode 4?

Comment: This same thing happened to me... I had to revert to an older working version (git)... I'm not sure there is anything you can do unless you have some sort of version control on your file

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026621/use-a-newer-version-of-xcode/19029344?noredirect=1#19029344

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually this has a very simple answer.

Open the Storyboard file on Xcode 5, And then:

1. Open file inspector
2. On **Interface Builder Documents** section change **Open with** to Xcode 4.6 (if it's 5.x).
3. Save, Close the project and open that with old Xcode.

It should work now.

This is same method like on earlier releases so I assume that's ok for NDA case (you can do the same thing on Xcode 4.6 to work with older version).

Comment: Confirmed to still work with Xcode 5 DP3 that was released today.

Comment: Its amazing. quiet amazing and hats off too the guy.

Comment: The Deployment and Development sections (drop downs) are disabled at my side under Interface Builder Documents section of file inspector. I'm using Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503)

Comment: @Ans You should do that with Xcode 5...then use old Xcode. Please read my instructions carefully.