# xcode 5 code not opening in xcode 4.6.3

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode4.6.3

I work on Xcode 4.6.3. After the new Xcode 5 beta arrived, I downloaded it and tried to run my code in it. It worked perfectly well in it. But now when I tried to open it with Xcode 4.6.3, it is not opening.

My guess is, all the xibs are updated. But making them compatible with Xcode 4.6.3 will be rework.

Is there any trick for this? Please do let me know.

PS: I am not using ARC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, *exactly*, does "it is not opening" mean?

Comment: If it's just the .xib files that are the problem, then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176160/xcode-5-to-xcode-4-project-run) may ave a solution for you.

Comment: Xcode 5 is under NDA. You should move this discussion to the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Just update/revert to a previous version of your project from your source control tool. Also, next time branch before you try using a new IDE on your project.