# Apportable app shows black screen

Tags: apportable

I made it to compile my app using apportable. However when running on device it just shows a black screen I have tried cleaning, reseting... etc. But no luck it just shows black screen, the project was done using XCode 5 and during the opengl selection I tried OpenGLES1/2(just in case), however no luck at all. Here's what apportable debug has to say:

warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0x40181b79 to 0x40181b78.

0x401e5408 in epoll_wait ()

from /Users/pabloivan57/.apportable/cache/devices/015d2ea4ce4c2208/libs/libc.so

$1 = 0

Breakpoint 1 at 0x6b7b01ac: file /Users/pabloivan57/Documents/Scopic Projects/Debrief/svn/Debrief/Debrief/main.m, line 3.

Breakpoint 2 at 0x62acf7b0

[New Thread 25402]

[Switching to Thread 25402]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=0, argv=0x6b629c08 <_start_method>)

```
at /Users/pabloivan57/Documents/Projects/Deb/svn/Deb/Deb/main.m:3
```

3   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

And the manifest:

```
      package="com.gcap.debrief"

      android:sharedUserId="com.gcap.debrief"

      android:installLocation="auto"

      android:versionCode="1387670144"

      android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="false"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"

             android:name="com.apportable.app.VerdeApplication"

             android:hasCode="true"

             android:icon="@drawable/icon"

             android:theme="@style/FullScreenActivity"

             android:debuggable="true"

             android:largeHeap="false"

             android:hardwareAccelerated="false"><meta-data android:name="android.app.libs" android:value="v cxx System objc pthread_workqueue dispatch ffi Foundation freetype CoreGraphics BridgeKit CoreText OpenAL verde" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="verde" />

    <meta-data android:name="android.app_name" android:value="Debrief" />

    <meta-data android:name="apportable.splash_screen_type" android:value="letterbox" />

    <meta-data android:name="apportable.orientation" android:value="portrait" />

    <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles2" android:value="true" />

    <meta-data android:name="apportable.opengles.fast_color" android:value="true" />

    <meta-data android:name="apportable.abi_list" android:value="" />

    <activity android:name="com.apportable.activity.VerdeActivity"

              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

              android:label="@string/app_name"

              android:screenOrientation="portrait"

              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

              android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.apportable.activity.GdbServerService"

        android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">

        <intent-filter >

            <action android:name="com.gcap.debrief.GdbServerService" />

        </intent-filter>

    </service>

    <service android:name="com.apportable.media.AudioManagerService" android:exported="false" />

    <service android:name="com.apportable.iap.BillingService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.apportable.iap.BillingReceiver">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY" />

            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE" />

            <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED" />

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else, help here is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apportable does not yet support xcode 5 xibs. They need to be [saved in xcode 4 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176160/xcode-5-to-xcode-4-project-run). More background in this [Apportable discuss thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apportable-discuss/xcode$205$20xib/apportable-discuss/9OV5K7Uv2UU/emmgllxZFzgJ).

If you still see a white screen, post the tail of adb logcat after the white screen comes up.

Comment: Thanks, effectively that was the reason